# IE9 XAML Security - Does a Full-Trust Certificate suffice?

Tags: xaml, internet-explorer-9, ssl-certificate, xbap, full-trust

Recently the IE developers (in their infinte wisdom) enhanced the way IE9 security works when it downloads an XAML browser file - which I need to do as I have a Winforms application hosted 'within' an XBAP

IE9 now requires me (as a user) to go onto its Security panel and click on 'Enable XAML browser applications' before it will run my application.

Now while I am more than happy to purchase  a Full-Trust certificate from a provider (e.g. Symantec) my question is this:

'With this certificate attached to my website - and by implication my application - will users STILL have to re-configure their browser(s) to 'Enable XAML browser applications' before my application runs, or will the Full-Trust certificate be enough to allow it to run seamlessly i.e. without the user modifying their browser settings?'

For what its worth my application might be used by hundreds (or hopefully) thousands of people, and I would hate the thought of them all having to change their browser settings to gasp in awe at its beauty(!!).

Will a Full-Trust certificate attached to it avoid this problem?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the certificate makes no difference in this case.